# What is the exact meaning of the question "Where do you come from"?

Tags: questions, present-simple

It is constructed in present simple. So it asks where I am coming from in general. How one can answer this question?

I know this question is correctly asked but I can't understand its meaning or what purpose it serves to. Can someone explain?

Note: I read [Difference between "where are you from" and "where do you come from"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/29957/difference-between-where-are-you-from-and-where-do-you-come-from). It mainly concerns about differences, so it doesn't answer my question. It is not a duplicate.

Comment: It *has* no exact meaning without context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't have an exact meaning - you yourself say "in general" in your queston. (Pretty much nothing does in conversational English).

One could quite legitimately answer "two stops away" if the question was asked on a bus, or "Earth" if asked on a distant space-station.

This phrase is most commonly used as part of "small talk" i.e. where the questioner is merely "making conversation" and doesn't actually care what the answer is.